# Dropping RSTs vs using NOTRACK

Tags: networking, iptables, tcp, tcp-ip

I'm in process building my own firewall. One can say I'm building user space TCP/IP stack.

However, When Kernel receive packet that it can't identify, Kernel would send out RST + ACK (Not sure whether it sends out an ACK (Update: It appear it does send out ACK)).

Since, I don't open any ports, I need somehow a way to override the Kernel's default behavior.

I found that people suggested to use IP Tables to block Outgoing RSTs and also found an answer that suggest to use NOTRACK.

I don't know how NOTRACK works and it's pro's and con's. Blocking RST gives me another challenge because I need to close connection but Blocking RSTs make it hard to send out my own RSTs.

```
iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -p tcp --port 8080 -j NOTRACK
```

My assumption is that this rule would block out Kernel taking control of the packets coming to 8080 port and if it's true, it would be far better than blocking RSTs.

Update:

I actually got to test this with Wireshark. It appear even after adding NOTRACK rule, the RST still sent and therefore, I'm unsure what NOTRACK for.

```
iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -p tcp --sport 443 -j NOTRACK
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NOTRACK` prevents that connection to be tracked in connection tracking.

Comment: Can't it prevent RSTs going out?

Comment: @sqlbie It is not in any way related to dropping packets.